# Exibir relacionamento de classe no DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando exibir um relacionamento de classe no DataGridView mas não estou conseguindo. Tenho 3 classes `Produto` e `Unidade` e `ItemVenda`, a classe `Unidade` referencia-se a unidade do produto se é KG/LT/UN etc...No DataGridView quero exibir o ItemVenda que é o Produto e sua Unidade porém, consigo apenas exibir o Produto e quando tento exibir a Unidade não funciona. Quando exibo o resultado da consulta em um `foreach` a unidade é exibida porém não consigo exibir no DataGridView.

Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**Classes**

```
public class Unidade{
   public Integer id {set;get;}
   public String descricao {set;get;};

   public Unidade(){}
}

public class Produto{
    public Long id {set;get;};
    public String descricao {set;get;};
    public Unidade unidade {set;get;}

    public Produto(){}
}

public class ItemVenda{
    public Long id {set;get;}
    public Produto produto {set;get;}

    public ItemVenda(){}
}
```

**Exibindo no DataGridView**

```
private void defineGrid(){
   gridItensVenda.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   IList<ItemVenda> lista = new ItemVendaDAO().findItensByVenda(venda);
   gridItensVenda.DataSource = lista;

   //exibe o produto
   DataGridViewColumn c1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   c1.DataPropertyName = "produto";
   c1.HeaderText = "Produto";

   //exibe a unidade do produto
   DataGridViewColumn c2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   c2.DataPropertyName = "ItemVenda.produto.unidade";
   c2.HeaderText = "Unidade";

   //adiciona columns ao grid
   gridItensVenda.Columns.Add(c1);
   gridItensVenda.Columns.Add(c2);   

}
```

Comment: Esta usando entity framework?